# phalcon volt extend not work

Tags: phalcon, volt

Taking problem with usibg `extends` in template

application/views/index/index.volt
first(actrually only one) line is:

```
{% extends common/index.volt %}
```

receive this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Phalcon\Mvc\View\Exception' with
>   message 'Extends statement must be placed at the first line in the
>   template in ../application/views/index/index.volt on line 1' in
>   ....\public_html\index.php on line 169

....\public_html\index.php line 169 is:

```
echo $application->handle()->getContent();
```

In demos http://docs.phalconphp.com/ru/latest/reference/volt.html#id33 just used including

So just cant understend if phalcon support `extends` or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your editor has inserted a BOM at the beginning of the .volt file? Go to your editor's encoding options (or the encoding menu) and choose "UTF-8 without BOM".

Comment: yeah... for some reason EF BB were first 2 bytes. removed - now works

Comment: That's what happens when you have devs working on M$ Windows. They put shitload of wrong data in files w/o even knowing it xD